# Dynamic variable handling in Redshift stored procedures

Tags: variables, stored-procedures, dynamic, amazon-redshift, execute

Hi I have a requirement where I am executing a query through stored procedures in aws redshift. I need to have the column name or table name to be dyanamic something like in the below example.[Table Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg968.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg968.png)
In this table I want to execute the query of id=3 but I want the table name(i) to be sent from my procedures while I call the procedure.
eg; Create table ro.test4(id integer); #should be executed

```
create or replace procedure ro.template()
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
i varchar(20);
name varchar(100);
begin
  i='test4';
  execute 'select(select query from rwr_dataops.test where id=3)'into name;
  raise info '%',name;
end;
$$

call ro.template();
```

I tried this procedure code but it is not working.Can somebody help me on this.

```
create or replace procedure ro.template()
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
i varchar(20);
name varchar(100);
begin
  i='test4';
  execute 'select(select query from rwr_dataops.test where id=3)'into name;
  raise info '%',name;
end;
$$

call ro.template();
```

not working
output is Create table ro.i(id integer); is executed
Expected : Create table ro.test4(id integer); #should be executed

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 EXECUTE statements - one to grab the SQL from the test table and one to execute this SQL statement.

Here's a quick set of SQL to demonstrate:

```
create table test as select 'select \'fubar\';' as query;

create or replace procedure template()
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
name varchar(100);
command varchar(100);
begin
  execute 'select query from test 'into command;
  execute command into name;
  raise info '%',name;
end;
$$;

call template();
```

This is a round-about way to display the text 'fubar' but you should see how this maps to your case.